# mongoimport: append source field

Tags: mongodb, import

With mongoimport I import the data of several external instances.

Does mongoimport allow me to add a field like source:"where-the-data-comes-from" to each document which is imported?

I.e. if i import the data of server A and B, I would like to store source:"A" or source:"B" to each document.

Answer (score 4):

No. However, you can do this from the command line. Create a file 'header.txt' containing, e.g., (you can create this from your existing csv) by running

`cat <(head -1 test.csv | tr "," "\n") <(echo source-a) > header.txt`

header.txt should look like this:
`field_a`
`field_b`
`.......`
`source`

*note I have appended a 'source' field to this document.
Now you can run the command (assuming you have sed installed)

`sed 's/$/,source-a/' test.csv  | mongoimport -d test-db -c test-cl --type csv --fieldFile header.txt`

If you already have a header line in your document, run

`sed '1d' test.csv | sed 's/$/,source-a/'  | mongoimport -d test -c test --type csv --fieldFile header.txt` instead - where 'source-a' is the label you want with this document.
You can easily script this in bash so that you only supply the source and csv for each import job.